# Querying and retrieving data from Mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql table using python but keep getting an error. Please see my attempt below and the data:

```
import MySQLdb
# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="world")
cursor = db.cursor()
t=['red', 'yellow']

for x in t:
    cursor.execute("select * from mytable where colours=%s," [x])
```

I got the following error:`TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

I learnt Mysql stores data as tuples, hence I would need change %s to a tuple but don't know how.

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: `cursor.execute("select * from mytable where colours=%s",[x])` comma misplaced ?

Comment: @NagendraNigade, well spotted, many thanks for you good eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and check if this resolve your problem

```
import MySQLdb
# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="world")
cursor = db.cursor()
t=['red', 'yellow']

for x in t:
    cursor.execute("select * from mytable where colours=%s" % repr(x))
```

Please note that here the `Sql Query` will build like

```
select * from mytable where colours='red'   #which is actual and correct query
```

Though I have not tested yet and there could be alternate way of doing this. The actual problem with OP problem is that it build `Sql Query` like

```
select * from mytable where colours=red  # Check the missing quotation around text red
```

Comment: good one, it worked. Please can you leave some explanation below. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and tell me where you did not get it.

Comment: I ran into a different problem and would really appreciate your suggestion. Here is what I fetched out ('red', '[1,2,3,4]'). Can you convert `'[1,2,3,4]'` to just a list?

Comment: I dont know if i am right but it seems you want ```sql query``` with ```in clause```.. So if this true then you can try using ```select * from mytable where range in %s' % str(tuple(x['red']))``` where ```x['red'] = [1,2,3,4]```  # you can use ```repr``` as well

Comment: I am not doing it for red alone, I am iterating over lots of other data.

Comment: I will suggest to create and post a sample problem, because it would be hard to understand what you want to achieve but the trick is what i have already mention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78592/discussion-between-mankur-and-user2274879).

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over the element in `t`. Therefore you do not need the `[]` around `x`:

```
import MySQLdb
# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="world")
cursor = db.cursor()
t=['red', 'yellow']

for x in t:
    cursor.execute("select * from mytable where colours=%s", x)
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt, Nagendra Nigade has already spotted the error in my code.